# Remove row with all NaN from DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame `df1`, `df2`, which I want to combine to the new dataframe `df`. This however creates an row with all NaN:

```
>>> from pandas import  DataFrame
>>> df1 = DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4]})
>>> df2 = DataFrame({'col1':[4,2,5], 'col2':[6,3,5]})

>>> df = df2[~df2.isin(df1)]
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     4     6
1   NaN   NaN
2     5     5
```

How can I remove this row, such that `df` looks like:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     4     6
2     5     5
```

Comment: Notice that a row filled with `NaN`is **not** an empty row.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use [dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
In [13]: df2[df1 != df2].dropna(how='all')
Out[13]: 
   col1  col2
0     4     6
2     5     5
```

Comment: what is the difference between dropna() and dropna(how='all')?

Comment: `dropna()` is the same as `dropna(how='any')` be default. This will drop *any* row which has a NaN. `dropna(how='all')` will drop a row only if *all* the values in the row are NaN.

Comment: I found this reference to pandas.DataFrame.dropna useful. Thanks, @unutbu. Just to clarify for any future readers, ```dropna(how='any')``` will drop *all* rows/columns (depending on which axis you select) which contain *any* NaN values. Subtle difference, but worth mentioning while I'm here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df = df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(1)]
>>> df
    col1  col2
0     4     6
2     5     5
```

Comment: You could also use `df1 == df2` in place of `df2.isin(df1)`.