# How can I drop missing from hundreds of columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    ...    col10000
10      NaN     25      ...    5
NaN     100     NaN     ...    5
35      NaN     NaN     ...    5
999     1900    500     ...    5
.
.
.
```

How can I drop all rows in which the columns from col1 to col300 are missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove row with all NaN from DataFrame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579285/remove-row-with-all-nan-from-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
cols = ["col{}".format(i) for i in range(1,301)]
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=cols)
```

Comment: This works if the columns are actually named as in the sample. It will fail if the names are just representatives.

Comment: The OP asked for col1 to col300. If they are named something else, they can be represented using `cols` and `dropna()` still works as proposed.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a manual check:

```
df[df.iloc[:,:300].notna().all(axis=1)]
```

or pass the first 300 columns as `subset` in `dropna`:

```
df.dropna(subset=df.columns[:300])
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just keep the columns you want?
`cols_to_keep = ['A','B','C']
df = df [cols_to_keep]`, this might also be the fastest way and independent of the count of irrelevant columns.

Comment: @OliverPrislan OP wants to check 300 columns. I don’t think manually type ‘cols_to_keep` is a good idea.

Comment: This will not work if the columns are not the first 300 columns. It is better to use column names to prevent any bugs.

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would use `dropna` but it seems like `loc` is a better fit in this case.

Starting with

```
    col1  coln  col300
0   3.0   2.0   NaN
1   2.0   NaN   1.0
2   NaN   2.0   5.0
```

In a single line

```py
df.loc[(pd.isnull(df.col1)==False) & (pd.isnull(df.col300)==False)]

#   col1    coln    col300
#1  2.0     NaN      1.0
```

This is doing an element-wise operation on two boolean columns, then feeding that to loc to filter by row.

```py
(pd.isnull(df.col1)==False) & (pd.isnull(df.col300)==False)

#0    False
#1     True
#2    False
#dtype: bool
```